# How to pass cURL result to variable

Tags: php, codeigniter, curl

Hi all I need help regarding cURL, I'm new to using cURL in PHP so I want to ask this.

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $get_url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1)');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$variable = curl_exec($curl);
```

$variable's value is boolean while cURL echoes a string during execution. Is there anyway I could get that echoed string pass to a variable?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the option `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);` to return the result as a string, in your case the string will be stored in `$variable`. Then, pass `$variable` to whatever function you desire.

Comment: right at the bat my friend!.. I'm taking this as the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is this way:

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $get_url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1)');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

ob_start();
curl_exec($curl);
$variable = ob_get_clean();
```

Comment: I will give you an upvote since you took time to contribute :D